# Installing Anchor on a MacOS -> Anchor versions are not matching up

Tags: solana

New to using Anchor for Solana. I just installed Anchor along with Solana and Rust, Solana and Rust were successfully installed, but I have been having issues with Anchor.

Whenever I check the Anchor version or do anything like Anchor init, I get an error stating that the Anchor version installed is incorrect.

```
mabeloza@Mabels-MacBook-Pro ~ % anchor --version
Only x86_64 / Linux distributed in NPM package right now.
Trying globally installed Anchor.
Globally installed anchor version is not correct. Expected "anchor-cli 0.18.2", found "anchor-cli 0.18.0".
```

The error is self-explanatory, I need the Anchor version 0.18.2. The problem is that this version of Anchor doesn't exist, if you look at the github page the latest version is 0.18.0.

https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/releases/tag/v0.18.0

I am following the instructions found on the Anchor page (https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/getting-started/installation.html), is there a different fork/version of the Anchor project I should be using?

Thank you all for your contribution!

Comment: Looks like you're installing the linux x86_64 version but it looks like you're running macos. Did you compile from source as the docs said?

Comment: You can also try to build from the source. Clone the repo and run `make build-cli`. Yes ^ try whatever Dominik said!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **MacOS** to install Anchor

1. Install Solana

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.8.0/install)"
```

2. Install Yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
```

3. Install Rust Cargo

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

4. Install Anchor by building the Rust project from Github and then installing the dependencies

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.18.0 anchor-cli --locked
```

```
npm install -g @project-serum/anchor
```

**Note:** Make sure the versions are the latest

Comment: @SibaprasadMaiti - ya, this should be taken down and replaced with just your link.  It's out-dated.  Can you put your link in as a comment under the question?  And I'll delete this post.

Comment: Links should be used sparingly in SO, as they end up broken, as this one has. Was able to find that post though and it didn't have the necessary info for Mac